# Calculate Difference between dates by group in R

Tags: r, date-arithmetic

I'm using a logistic exposure to calculate hatching success for bird nests.  My data set is quite extensive and I have ~2,000 nests, each with a unique ID ("ClutchID).  I need to calculate the number of days a given nest was exposed ("Exposure"), or more simply, the difference between the 1st and last day.  I used the following code:

```
HS_Hatch$Exposure=NA    
for(i in 2:nrow(HS_Hatch)){HS_Hatch$Exposure[i]=HS_Hatch$DateVisit[i]- HS_Hatch$DateVisit[i-1]}
```

where HS_Hatch is my dataset and DateVisit is the actual date.  The only problem is R is calculating an exposure value for the 1st date (which doesn't make sense).

What I really need is to calculate the difference between the 1st and last date for a given clutch.  I've also looked into the following:

```
Exposure=ddply(HS_Hatch, "ClutchID", summarize, 
                     orderfrequency = as.numeric(diff.Date(DateVisit)))


df %>%
  mutate(Exposure =  as.Date(HS_Hatch$DateVisit, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(ClutchID) %>%
  arrange(Exposure) %>%
  mutate(lag=lag(DateVisit), difference=DateVisit-lag)
```

I'm still learning R so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Below is a sample of the data I'm using

```
HS_Hatch <- structure(list(ClutchID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), DateVisit = c("3/15/2012", "3/18/2012", "3/20/2012", "4/1/2012", 
                 "4/3/2012", "3/18/2012", "3/20/2012", "3/22/2012", "4/3/2012", 
                 "4/4/2012", "3/22/2012", "4/3/2012", "4/4/2012", "3/18/2012", 
                 "3/20/2012", "3/22/2012", "4/2/2012", "4/3/2012", "4/4/2012", 
                 "3/20/2012", "3/22/2012", "3/25/2012", "3/27/2012", "4/4/2012", 
                 "4/5/2012"), Year = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
                                       2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
                                       2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
                                       2012L), Survive = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .Names = c("ClutchID", 
                                                                                                                                                                                         "DateVisit", "Year", "Survive"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                             ClutchID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), DateVisit = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), Survive = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector"))), .Names = c("ClutchID", "DateVisit", "Year", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "Survive")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: maybe `summarise(exposure=diff(range(DateVisit)))` ?

Comment: what @BenBolker said, just to add that his `summarise` line should go after your `group_by` line. And depending on the class of `DateVisit` you can either leave off your first `mutate` line, or change the `summarise` line to reference `Exposure` instead of `DateVisit`.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add the data _properly formatted_ there, not in a comment and not as a link. Using `dput` is preferred. Thank you.

Comment: @rosscova I modified the code per your Ben Boke suggestions, but I'm getting the following error message: "Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function"  I tried removing the 1st mutate function but then I get this message: "  no applicable method for 'regroup' applied to an object of class "Date"         Like I mentioned I'm not super familiar with R and coding so I don't understand these error messages

Comment: First, please heed the `dput` suggestion above. Have you removed the last few lines of code in your question off? I'll leave putting all this together in an answer to @BenBolker if he wants to.

Comment: @rosscova 1)I'm sorry, I don't understand how to properly format data with dput. Where can I find out more about that?  2)Which lines of code are you referring to?

Comment: One of your proximal problems is that `plyr` and `dplyr` both have `mutate` functions. Try specifying `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: @BenBolker good point, except I think that the problematic mask might be with `summarise` should your first comment be implemented

Answer (score 8):

Collecting some of the comments...

## Load `dplyr`

We need only the `dplyr` package for this problem. If we load other packages, e.g. `plyr`, it can cause conflicts if both packages have functions with the same name. Let's load only `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
```

In the future, you may wish to load `tidyverse` instead -- it includes `dplyr` and other related packages, for graphics, etc.

## Converting dates

Let's convert the `DateVisit` variable from character strings to something R can interpret as a date. Once we do this, it allows R to calculate differences in days by subtracting two dates from each other.

```
HS_Hatch <- HS_Hatch %>%
 mutate(date_visit = as.Date(DateVisit, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

The date format `%m/%d/%Y` is different from your original code. This date format needs to match how dates look in your data. `DateVisit` has dates as month/day/year, so we use `%m/%d/%Y`.

Also, you don't need to specify the dataset for `DateVisit` inside `mutate`, as in `HS_Hatch$DateVisit`, because it's already looking in `HS_Hatch`. The code `HS_Hatch %>% ...` says 'use `HS_Hatch` for the following steps'.

## Calculating exposures

To calculate exposure, we need to find the first date, last date, and then the difference between the two, for each set of rows by `ClutchID`. We use `summarize`, which collapses the data to one row per `ClutchID`.

```
exposure <- HS_Hatch %>% 
    group_by(ClutchID) %>%
    summarize(first_visit = min(date_visit), 
              last_visit = max(date_visit), 
              exposure = last_visit - first_visit)
```

`first_visit = min(date_visit)` will find the minimum `date_visit` for each `ClutchID` separately, since we are using `group_by(ClutchID)`.

`exposure = last_visit - first_visit` takes the newly-calculated `first_visit` and `last_visit` and finds the difference in days.

This creates the following result:

```
  ClutchID first_visit last_visit exposure
     <int>      <date>     <date>    <dbl>
1        1  2012-03-15 2012-04-03       19
2        2  2012-03-18 2012-04-04       17
3        3  2012-03-22 2012-04-04       13
4        4  2012-03-18 2012-04-04       17
5        5  2012-03-20 2012-04-05       16
```

If you want to keep all the original rows, you can use `mutate` in place of `summarize`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure this out.  As someone who is still learning R coding, I appreciate you explaining the code step-by-step.  I was able to understand it and follow along.

Comment: Click "accept" if the answer solves your problem. This will help saying thank you to the responder, and will help others find the solution in the future.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Upon replicating this example, for exposure, I only get returned one line. The grouping factor is ignored. Do you experience the same issue? Or is it because I'm using a newer version perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was able to replicate it with R 3.4.3 and dplyr 0.7.4. What does your one row result look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solutions if you look for a difftime results in days, from a vector `date`, without NA values produce in the new column, and if you expect to group by several conditions/groups.

make sure that your vector of date as been converting in the good format as previously explained.

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
select(group1, group2, date) %>% 
arrange(group1, group2, date) %>% 
group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
mutate(diff_date = c(0,diff(date)))
```