# How to subtract from two columns grouped by another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a genetic dataset of chromosome positions, I am trying to use the positions to find gene lengths. For example:

```
#Input:
Chr  Start  End   Genes
1      1     2    Gene1
1      3     4    Gene1
1      5     9    Gene2 
2      1     3    Gene3


#Expected output calculating gene lengths:
Chr  Start  End   Genes     Length
1      1     2    Gene1      3     
1      3     4    Gene1      3
1      5     9    Gene2      4
2      1     3    Gene3      2
```

So I am looking to find for each gene the maximum `End` value minus the minimum `Start` value and put that value in a new `Length` column.

I've been trying to go about this with something like:

```
test <- df %>%
  group_by(Genes) %>%
  df$Length = (min(df$Start) - max(df$End))
```

I've also been trying to find a `data.table` solution (as my real data is very big) but I am not experienced.

Comment: Are you sure your expected lengths are correct? For Gene1 `max(End) = 4` and `min(Start) = 1`. Also note you need to wrap the calculations in `mutate()` and not use `df$` every time. Just the variable names are needed, i.e. `.... %>% mutate(Length = (min(Start) - max(End)))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570221/calculate-difference-between-dates-by-group-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you were trying to do :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Genes) %>% mutate(Length = max(End) - min(Start))
```

which in `data.table is :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Length :=  max(End) - min(Start), Genes]
```